# Codeigniter 3.1.0 Active Record Update Query Neither Errors Nor Updates Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, activerecord

Despite my best efforts at following the CI 3.1.0 documentation concerning standard CRUD update procedure, I'm never able to have the targeted db elements update with information entered into my edit form. Currently, this is the code determining my update flow (in its' entirety);

**EDIT FORM (edit.php - view file)**

```
<div id="container">

    <h1>Edit Post: <?php echo $post[0]['title']; ?></h1>

    <?php if($msg = $this->session->flashdata("message")): ?>
    <p class="success">
      <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form action="<?php echo base_url('submit/update'); ?>" method="POST">
    <p>
    <label for="title">Title edit:</label>
    <input type="text" name="post[title]" id="title" value="<?php echo $post[0]['title'];?>"/>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="article_text">Content edit:</label>
    <textarea name="post[article]" id="article" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $post[0]['article_text']; ?></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
    <label for="category">Category edit:</label>
    <SELECT name="post[category]" id="category" value="<?php echo $post[0]['category'];?>">
            <OPTION>CODING</OPTION> 
            <OPTION>DOWNLOADS</OPTION>
            <OPTION>HUMOR</OPTION> 
            <OPTION>IMAGES</OPTION>
            <OPTION>INFO</OPTION>
            <OPTION>MMO</OPTION>
            <OPTION>MULTIMEDIA</OPTION> 
            <OPTION>RANDOM</OPTION>
            <OPTION>REVIEWS</OPTION>
            <OPTION>TUTORIALS</OPTION> 
    </SELECT>
    </p>

    <p>
    <input type="hidden" name="post[article_id]"  id="article_id" value="<?php echo $post[0]['article_id'];?>" />
    <input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Edit article" name="submit">
    </p>
      </form>
      </div>
```

If anyone's wondering why I don't just append `$article_id` to my `form action`, 
it's because, for some reason, it keeps nulling the elements I'm targeting for update. I'm packing `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in the submit controller `parent::__construct();` to make sure that the correct data is being pulled into the edit page, targeting the correct `$article_id` for editing. This is the form prior to any attempt to update it;

[image: CRUD Edit Form]
**Submit Controller Update Function (submit.php)**

```
function update()
    {
         $this->load->model('article_model');
         $article_id = $this->input->post('article_id')
         $this->Article->updateData($article_id);                       
    }
```

**Article Model Update Function**

```
//UPDATE DATA FROM TINYMCE INTO DB TABLE
function updateData($article_id)
{       
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $article = $this->input->post('article_text');
    $category = $this->input->post('category');

    $data = array(
        'title'=> $title,
        'article_text'=>$article,
        'category'=>$category
    );
    $this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('article_id', $this->input->post('article_id'));
    $this->db->update('articles', $data);
    redirect('submit/manage', 'refresh');
    exit;
}
```

I'd previously experimented with `$this->db->replace`, but that errored out as inserting `NULL` into the db for those targeted elements. I've tried about all I can as enabled by the CI 3 docs and SO answer inventory. And neither my WAMP solution error logs nor the CI application log are throwing me any bones. Fresh out of ideas on this issue...

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks to something @DFriend mentioned in the comments, I was able to get an error message that let me know that the `set` method was required for the update process. I saw another notation while I was on the hunt here @ SO in the vein of;

```
$this->db->set('title', $title);
$this->db->set('article_text', $article);
$this->db->set('category', $category);
$this->db->where('article_id', $article_id);
$this->db->update('articles');
```

But, alas, **no joy** as I get the same result as last coding attempt where I'm shunted back to the CRUD article list with nary a change in sight. Going to be a long night...

**DAYBREAK**

Sometimes it's fun to wander around in circles all night (not...), through the labyrinth of documentation, really trying to hash out its' vagaries. One of the few nuggets I came away with was `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`. Intuitively, I removed the `redirect()` call at the end of the `updateData()` function, and lo and behold...

[image: CI 3 Profiler output info]

So it's confirmed that there **is** postdata, but something is causing only `NULL` entries for those targeted elements. This a lot better situation to be in than the previous. Would be great if the Profiler could also locate the `NULL` sourcing for me (lol!), but then again, that's **my** job...

Comment: Are the `$this->input->post` calls in `updateData()` returning the values you expect?

Comment: @DFriend, I'm absolutely getting the values as they're pulled into the edit form (and I checked with var_dump beforehand). I also had an error-checking device at the end of the `updateData()` function to trap any to display in-browser.

Comment: Probably not the issue and you probably know this, but ` $this->db->update` won't do anything if the supplied values are the same as those already in the specified row.

Comment: Have you examined the table with phpMyAdmin (or other tool) before and after the update attempt? Might be the table is updated but new data isn't getting displayed?

Comment: True, @DFriend, but the elements of the row that I'm targeting, have unique values to be added, and I only include three of the four `$this->input->post();` from the previous submit form structure as I'm not allowing one of the values to be changed. Thanks for your eyes...

Comment: Have indeed checked the table (via PHPMyAdmin) and there was no change (which I can also see is the case from my CRUD article listing). I'm perplexed as the `insert` process was an absolute no-brainer. **Why does the** `update` **process have to be such a pain in the backside?** (lol!).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125959/discussion-between-dfriend-and-homeoffice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA....Nailed it!**

Something smacked me in the back of the head to compare the submission forms for both the `submit` and `edit` pages. As I'd been customizing a tutorial for my own usage, I neglected to change form elements to reflect db column residents;

```
name="post[title]" != name="title"
name="post[article]" != name="article_text" 
name="post[category]" != name="category"
```

It was just these three elements stuffing it up for me, and blocking the postdata from the form from inserting into the database. Now, there is joy in my world...This is the initial Article Manager before;

[image: Before Editing Article Manager View]

And now, after application of my code edit...

[image: After View in Article Manager]

@DFriend, I'm going to be upvoting your answer as I believe it was ultra helpful (along with those thought-provoking comments from you as well) to me and will be of use to others down the line as this answer is searched out in the future. For those who may be struggling with this issue, this is my final overview;

**EDIT FORM (edit.php - view file)**

```
<div id="container">

<h1>Edit Post: <?php echo $post[0]['title']; ?></h1>

<?php if($msg = $this->session->flashdata("message")): ?>
<p class="success">
  <?php echo $msg; ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<form action="<?php echo base_url('submit/update'); ?>" method="POST">
<p>
<label for="title">Title edit:</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $post[0]['title'];?>"/>
</p>

<p>
<label for="article_text">Content edit:</label>
<textarea name="article_text" id="article_text" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $post[0]['article_text']; ?></textarea>
</p>

<p>
<label for="category">Category edit:</label>
<SELECT name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo $post[0]['category'];?>">
        <OPTION>CODING</OPTION> 
        <OPTION>DOWNLOADS</OPTION>
        <OPTION>HUMOR</OPTION> 
        <OPTION>IMAGES</OPTION>
        <OPTION>INFO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>MMO</OPTION>
        <OPTION>MULTIMEDIA</OPTION> 
        <OPTION>RANDOM</OPTION>
        <OPTION>REVIEWS</OPTION>
        <OPTION>TUTORIALS</OPTION> 
</SELECT>
</p>

<p>
<input type="hidden" name="article_id"  id="article_id" value="<?php echo $post[0]['article_id'];?>" />
<input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Edit article" name="submit">
</p>
  </form>
  </div>
```

**Submit Controller Update Function (submit.php)**

```
    function update()
    {
            $this->load->model('article_model');
            $article_id = $this->input->post('article_id');             
            $this->Article->updateData($article_id);                    
    }
```

**Article Model Update Function**

```
function updateData($article_id)
{       
   $title = $this->input->post('title');
   $article = $this->input->post('article_text');
   $category = $this->input->post('category');

   $data = array(
      'title'=> $title,
      'article_text'=>$article,
      'category'=>$category,
      'date'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   );
    $this->db->set('title', $title);
    $this->db->set('article_text', $article);
    $this->db->set('category', $category);
    $this->db->where('article_id', $article_id);
    $this->db->update('articles', $data);
    redirect('submit/manage', 'refresh');
    exit;
 }
```

The exhilaration of nailing this has driven away the need for sleep (lol!). Let's see how far I get before the Sandman catches me at the desk in the back of my head. **@DFriend, thanks again for your eyes and those deft comments. Couldn't have gotten here without your assistance...**

**Tying Up Loose Ends...**

Also for the benefit of anyone stumbling on this post: had to clone the article model `edit` function so that I could point it at the `delete.php` page (itself a clone of the `submit.php` page) with the `form action` of `base_url('submit/trash')` which took out the garbage for me effortlessly, redirecting to the article manager minus the deleted article.... And the last bit (earning me a functional application, to boot);

**DELETE FORM (delete.php - view page)**

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Delete Post: <?php echo $post[0]['title']; ?></h1>

<form action="<?php echo base_url('submit/trash'); ?>" method="POST">
<p>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input size="25" type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $post[0]['title'];?>" readonly />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="article_text">Content</label>
    <textarea readonly name="article_text" id="article_text" rows="12" cols="120"><?php echo $post[0]['article_text']; ?></textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <SELECT disabled name="category" id="category" value="">
            <OPTION><?php echo $post[0]['category'];?></OPTION> 
               </SELECT>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="hidden" name="article_id"  id="article_id" value="<?php echo $post[0]['article_id'];?>" />
        <input class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit" value="Delete article" name="submit">
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

**Submit Controller Delete Function (submit.php)**

```
function delete() //so we can show delete.php view page
{
        $this->load->model('article_model');

        $article_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $post = $this->Article->getArticle($article_id);
        if(!$post)
        {
            redirect('submit/manage', 'refresh');
            exit;
        }
         $data['post'] = $post;           
         $this->load->view('delete',$data);
    }
```

**Delete Form "action" function**

```
    function trash()
    {
            $this->load->model('article_model');
            $article_id = $this->input->post('article_id');             
            $this->Article->deleteData($article_id);                    
    }
```

**Article Model Delete Function**

```
function deleteData($article_id)
    {
       $this->db->where('article_id', $article_id);
       $this->db->delete('articles');
       redirect('submit/manage', 'refresh');
       exit;           
    }
```

**I really hope this post helps someone in the future. It's certainly helped me (lol!)...**

Answer (score 1):

Total shot in the dark as all the other bases seemed to be covered.

Suggested revision

```
//UPDATE DATA FROM TINYMCE INTO DB TABLE
function updateData($article_id)
{       
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $article = $this->input->post('article_text');
    $category = $this->input->post('category');

    $data = array(
        'title'=> $title,
        'article_text'=>$article,
        'category'=>$category,
        'date'=> date("Y-m-d H:i:s") //same data as NOW() only via PHP
    );
    //Here's the shot in the dark - set() is somehow screwing things up
    //$this->db->set('date', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('article_id', $article_id); //you passed  $article_id into the function so use it
    $this->db->update('articles', $data);
    redirect('submit/manage', 'refresh');
    //redirect ends with a call to exit so the next line would never execute anyway
    //exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that `shot in the dark`, but it came up with the same results as my attempt. Thanks for the mention of `var_dump($this->db->get_compiled_update());` (going to be adding this to the debug arsenal), which clued me in about the `set` method.